# C programming, reading from a file and loading into an array

Tags: c, arrays, file, input

I'm getting a few extra garbage characters after I print out the file I've read into an array.

Here is my code

```
fp = fopen("load.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    perror("Exiting, an error occured while opening\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    load[i++] = ch;

}

fclose(fp);

for(i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{

    printf("%c", load[i]);
}
```

Sample output

`The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
���������0LãUˇ���∞4
����������@LãUˇ��������������`

Notice all of the garbage after the sentence? I'm not sure what is causing this.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Post the entire relevant code please.

Comment: Please post the `load` declaration.

Comment: Are you reading about 45 characters (the length of "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.") and printing 100?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what did you expect to happen when you print 100 characters in the `for` loop???

1. Add `i = 0` before the `while` loop.
2. Add `load[i] = 0` after the `while` loop.
3. Replace the entire `for` loop with `printf("%s",load)`.

Also, assuming that the `load` array is statically allocated in the same function:

- Extend the condition of the `while` loop with `&& i < sizeof(load)-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing `load[i]` for all values of `i` from `0` to `99`, but never seem to assign to it beyond where the data read from the file ends. This means the rest of the array has garbage data, which is what you see when you print it.

To fix this, add a terminator symbol to the end of the data read from the file and break the for loop once it comes up.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on keeping your for loop:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)  //stop at the EOF you got earlier
{
    printf("%c", load[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In C, all strings have a null string terminator, the `\0` character. Since you already have the last character loaded, `i` then you can:

```
if (i >= 100) i = 100; // bounding checks
load[i] = '\0';
```

And for printing, you must:

```
int pos;
while ( pos = 0; pos < i; ++pos)
  printf("%c", load[pos]);
```

Or...

```
printf("%s", load);
```